# Profiling Javascript JIT in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, jit

I recently came across this awesome article and presentation about [Breaking the JavaScript Speed Limit with V8](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/). This is awesome!

However, I'm a Firefox fan and wondering if there's a way to profile the JIT for Mozilla's tools. Mostly I'd like to see if a compilation has to bail or is missing out on some kind of optimization that could otherwise be had.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in debug Firefox builds to some extent.  In an opt build you can install https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jit-inspector/ which will tell you what the JIT *is* doing, but not what it *could* have done....

Comment: Cool! Any tips or blogs on how to use it effectively or read the output?

Comment: I don't know of any offhand.  :(  I mostly use it to easily read the generated assembly on hot codepaths, but that's not all that useful for someone who's not actually hacking on the JIT...